# How to use database navigation plugin in phpstorm 3

Tags: php, sql, database, plugins, phpstorm

i am using phpstorm 3 and installed the plugin database navigator but i dont know to to config it to local server (WAMP) and remote server plz tell me what information i put on

name, description, driver , driver library, url, user and password field in connection setting.

Plz tell me in detail first how to set it locally after that how to connect it with remote server database.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to download and install any third-party plugins for this functionality, it's [provided out of the box](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/creating-and-importing-data-sources.html).

Sample configuration for MySQL would look like this:

[image: Data Source Properties]

Answer (score 0):

As of now, the Database Navigation plugin will cause the Ui to crash in PHPStorm version 3.0. So avoid it. As was already pointed out, a lot of what you need is already included.